# Prove that $\sum\frac{ x^2+n}{x^2+n^3}$ is not uniformly convergent on the domain $\Bbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Guys I got across this question in my last chapter of real analysis book. 
Prove that $\sum $$(x^2+n)\over(x^2+n^3)$ is not uniformly convergent on the domain $\Bbb R$.

This is Book's Answer:

When $x=n^2$, there is a term in the series, after the nth, which is greater than $1\over 2$. So altough the series is convergent for each value of x by comparison with $\sum 1/n^2$, the greatest difference between the nth partial sum (i. e.$f_n$) and limit function is not null.

The first statement in answer that book made is where I don't understand. Why is $x=n^2$ even choosed? How it came? And what does it mean by after nth term of it is greater than $1\over 2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uniform convergece of the series  $\sum f_n(x)$ a necessary condition is $f_n(x) \to 0$ uniformly. This means $\sup_x |f_n(x)| $ must tend to $0$. This forces $f_n(x_n)$ also to tend to $0$ for any sequence of numbers $(x_n)$ in the domain. So for proving that a series is not uniformly convergent you try to find $x_n$'s so that $f_n(x_n)$ does not tend to $0$.

The choice of $x_n$ used in the proof depends on the particular series. There is no general method. When $f_n$ is a ratio of two simple functions as in this case you try to choose $x_n$ so that the numerator and the denominator tend to $0$ or $\infty$ at the same rate so that the ratio tends to some non-zero number.  Basically you have to start guessing what $x_n$'s might work.

Comment: @StupidKid I have edited my answer. Sorry, no one can give a general procedure for choosing  $x_n$.

Comment: "When $x=n^2$, there is a term in the series, after the nth, which is greater than $1\over 2$. " Can you explain me this. I have really hard time understanding what it mean.

Comment: What they are saying is  $\frac {(n^{2})^{2}+n} {{(n^{2})^{2}+n^{3}}}$ or $\frac {n(n^{3}+1)}{n^{3}(n+1)}>\frac 1 2$ if $n$ is large enough. This is because $\frac {n(n^{3}+1)}{n^{3}(n+1)}=\frac {n^{3}+1} {n^{3}} \frac n {n+1} \to (1)(1)$ as $n \to \infty$.